# Loading images from web using Thre20 PhotoBrowser

Tags: iphone, image, three20

I'm having a strange problem with the PhotoBrowser of the Three20 library. I'm using this code to load images from the web:

```
self.photoSource = [[PhotoSource alloc]
initWithType:PhotoSourceNormal
title:@"JamesD Flyer"
photos:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
[[[Photo alloc] initWithURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3444/3223645618_13fe36887a_o.jpg"                                 smallURL:nil
size:CGSizeMake(320, 480)] autorelease],
[[[Photo alloc] initWithURL:@"http://www.james-dean.at/mainpage/flyer/2.jpg"
smallURL:nil  
size:CGSizeMake(409, 591)] autorelease],
[[[Photo alloc] initWithURL:@"http://www.james-dean.at/mainpage/flyer/1.jpg"
smallURL:nil  
size:CGSizeMake(409, 591)] autorelease],nil] photos2:nil];
```

The images 1 and 3 are being loaded without any problems but 2 isn't and I don't know why. It has the same dimension and resolution but still it's not loading.
Is there any way to trace what the iPhone is loading from the web?

Answer (score 0):

I would start setting a breakpoint in `TTPhotoViewController` `loadImages` selector.

Each photo is associated to a `TTPhotoView` and `loadImages` is responsible to create all those views.

From there, you could probably make your mind as to what is happening...

Comment: hmm, I'm pretty new in xCode so could you please be a little more detailed. I got the TTPhotoviewController inside of a TabBarController. Where can I find that loadImages that you mentioned? Thx anyway for your speedy reply :)

Comment: this is the location of the file, relative to three20 root: `src/Three20UI/Sources/TTPhotoViewController.m`, open it in Xcode and put a breakpoint in `loadImages` function.